# Average of Last 90 days data, but for each hour samples in a day using MDX query

Tags: mdx

I have a measure as 'power' rollup as SUM, Time dimension as Year->Month->Day->Hour, and Location Dimension.

We are storing at hour level of power data.

Now we require for a particular location and date, last 90 days average power for each hour.  It should display 24 columns with average last 90 days power_total for each hour.

The following query gives only that date's power for each hour for a location1. But I need last 90days average power for each hour in a date and location. How to do this requirement?

SELECT
{Hierarchize({[Time.Monthly].[2013].[9].[20].Children})} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {CROSSJOIN({Hierarchize({[Location].[Location1]})},{[Measures].[power]})} ON ROWS
FROM [Power_Trend]

I am pretty new to MDX.

Please help me out.

-Prakash

Answer (score 0):

You can use LAG function to create a date range: [description with some simple examples](http://www.mdxpert.com/Functions/MDXFunction.aspx?f=37)

Secondly you should create current date member with strtomember, for example:

```
strtomember("[Time.Monthly].["+cstr(year(now())) + "].[" + cstr(month(now())) + "].[" + cstr(day(now())) +"]")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right, I need to use Lag to find date range.  But I need data for each hour which suppose to lag for 90 days. That is where I am struck.  I mean at hour member level, but lag at day member level..

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same question in pentaho forum. It has bean answered.

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?150250-Average-of-Last-90-days-data-but-for-each-hour-samples-in-a-day&p=355155